# How can I convert a tensor with the shape of [1, 3, 64, 64] to [1, 4, 64, 64] with the newly added layer being the same as the previous?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a PyTorch tensor with the shape of `[1, 3, 64, 64]`, and I want to convert it to the shape `[1, 4, 64, 64]` while setting the value of the newly added layer to be the same as the previous layer in the same dimension (eg `newtensor[0][3] = oldtensor[0][2]`)

Note that my tensor has `requires_grad=True`, so I cannot use `resize_()`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a slice from the old tensor, and concatenate it to the new tensor along dimension 1.

```
tslice = old[:,-1:,:,:]
new = torch.cat((old,tslice), dim = 1)
```

Comment: I ran this, and got `RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 4 and 3`

Comment: Ah my bad, if you do [:,-1,:,:] it recognizes that dimension 1 has size 1 and automatically squeezes it, whereas if you do [:,-1:,:,:] it doesn't automatically squeeze. I edited my answer to reflect this. The notation is similar so easy to mix up

Answer (score 1):

This will work perfectly. @DerekG code had an error in `-1`, but his idea is correct.
`tensor` is your tensor data.

```
new = torch.cat((tensor, tensor[:, 0:1, :, :]), dim=1)
```

Comment: I think you should remove the space character at the beginning of your line. I just copy the line and it causes indentation error. There is no problem fixing it, but someone might copy it and doesn't know about the space

Comment: @raspiduino ^^ ok i edit my answer .